# Get rid of "Testing Notebook" toolbar

Tags: notebooks

I was messing around with different styles and tried the MUnit style. I converted back to Standard Report but I still see the toolbar for testing notebook. Is there a way to get rid of it?

[image: Want to get rid of this "toolbar"]

Comment: When I applied the style sheets to a Notebook the header (toolbar) disappeared when I selected StandardReport.  Does this problem occur for you with a new Notebook or only this particular one?

Comment: Only this notebook. Not sure what I changed though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should remove the "toolbar" from the Notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> {}]
```

If that cell remained after changing styles I think it is a glitch and should be reported.

Comment: I think this is a glitch, too. I have encountered this behavior with other kinds of templated notebooks as  well.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard! It did seem like a bug :- I'll send it along to Wolfram support.